# ffmpeg Too many packets buffered for output stream. when decoding rtsp stream from cheap camera

Tags: ffmpeg

I tried to record the video feed of a camera with `ffmpeg -i rtsp://admin:PASSWORDIP:554/11  -c:a aac -c:v copy -map 0 -f mp4 -y "output_file.mp4"`. I can view the stream via VLC, but ffmpeg gives me an error.

I have tried to fiddel with the bitrate and I tried to use tcp instead of udp, but i get the same error every time.
full logs:

```
Input #0, rtsp, from 'rtsp://admin:PASSWORD@IP:554/11':
  Metadata:
    title           : 10
  Duration: N/A, start: 0.200000, bitrate: N/A
    Stream #0:0: Video: h264 (Main), yuvj420p(pc, bt709, progressive), 1920x1080, 15 tbr, 90k tbn, 180k tbc
    Stream #0:1: Audio: pcm_alaw, 8000 Hz, mono, s16, 64 kb/s
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (copy)
  Stream #0:1 -> #0:1 (pcm_alaw (native) -> aac (native))
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
Too many packets buffered for output stream 0:0.-577014:32:22.77 bitrate=  -0.0kbits/s speed=N/A
Conversion failed!
```

Comment: Try add `-max_muxing_queue_size 4000` before output filename

Answer (score 0):

I think somehow the audio from that camera is malformed. when replacing the -c:a aac to -na. the errors went away. Even thow the protocal should be supported.